# Potential energy and atomic units in the Bohr model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, potential-energy, units

I have a question regarding the final sentence written in the solution to part iii) (found below) for the question given below.

> In the Bohr model of the hydrogen atom, the radius of the electron orbit in state $n$ is equal to $n^2a_0$, where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius.  The speed of the electron in state $n$ is $\alpha c/n$, where $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant. The energy of state $n$ is equal to $−{R_{\infty}}hc/n^2$, where $R_{\infty}$ is the Rydberg constant.  Expressions for $a_0$, $\alpha$ and $R_{\infty}$ are given below. Using these results, calculate the potential energy, the kinetic energy and the total energy of the $n=2$ state in hydrogen in terms of the Rydberg constant. Comment on the relation between these quantities.
>
> Useful information:
> $$a_0=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0{\hbar}^2}{me^2}$$
> $$\alpha=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar\,c}$$
> $$R_{\infty}=\frac{me^4}{2(4\pi\epsilon_0)^2\hbar^2}\frac{1}{hc}$$
> where the symbols have their usual meanings.

`Solution to part 1] i)`:

> $$r_n=n^2\,a_0$$ so $${\mathrm{PE}}=\frac{-e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\,r_n}=\frac{-e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\,n^2\,a_0}=-\frac{e^2me^2}{n^2(4\pi\epsilon_0)^2\hbar^2}$$
> Since $n=2$,
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
> {\mathrm{PE}=-\frac{R_{\infty}hc}{2}}\tag{1}$$
> Now n=2 for $$\mathrm{KE}=\frac12m{v_n}^2=\frac{m\,\alpha^2\,c^2}{2n^2}=\frac{R_{\infty}hc}{4}$$
> and $E=-\frac{R_{\infty}hc}{4}$
>
> So $\mathrm{E=PE+KE}$ as expected.

`Question 1] iii)`

> Given the (normalised) expression for the $2$p radial wavefunction below, calculate the expectation value of $1/r$ in the $2$p state. $\bbox[yellow]{\text{
> Compare your answer with the results in part (i) from the Bohr model.}}$
> $$R_{2\mathrm{p}}(r)=\left(\frac{1}{a_0}\right)^{3/2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}\frac{r}{a_0}e^{-r/2a_0}$$
> You may make use of the standard integral:
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^n\exp(-bx)dx=\frac{n!}{b^{n+1}}$$

`Solution to part 1] iii)`:

> $$R_{2\mathrm{p}}(r)=\left(\frac{1}{a_0}\right)^{3/2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}\frac{r}{a_0}e^{-r/2a_0}$$
> $$\begin{align}\Biggl\langle\frac{1}{r}\Biggr\rangle &=\int_0^\infty\lvert R_{2\mathrm{p}}(r)\rvert^2\frac{1}{r}r^2dr\\&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{{a_0}^3}\frac{1}{24}\frac{r^2}{{a_0}^2}\,r\,e^{-r/a_0}dr\\&=\frac{1}{24{a_0}^3}6{a_0}^4\\&=\frac14a_0\end{align}$$
>
> $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\text{Gives the same PE as the Bohr model as expected, since}\, r_{n=2}=n^2a_0=4a_0}$

---

I have marked in red the parts for which I don't understand. Why does it give the same PE as equation $(1)$? Before asking this question I did some digging around and found out that in atomic units $R_\infty hc=1/2$ and I note that from i) that $R_{\infty}hc$ has units of energy. Even with this, I still have no idea what the author saying in that last boxed sentence. Does it seem that $\frac14a_0=-\frac{R_{\infty}hc}{2}$?

Put simply, how does $\frac14a_0$ give a potential energy of $-\frac{R_{\infty}hc}{2}$?

Comment: Clearly it can’t as $a_0$ does not have units of energy.  You’re likely missing some factors in front of $\langle 1/r\rangle$.  The question should read: given this average value verify that this gives the right potential energy.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Well here is the [question](https://prnt.sc/xvztu3) and the two solutions [here](https://prnt.sc/xvzmdt) and [here](https://prnt.sc/xvzjbu) with the last [bit](https://prnt.sc/xw09mu) at the end. I can send you the whole exam paper if you want.

Comment: I’m sure you reproduced the question correctly just your interpretation of it (which is correct) is probably not how the author intended the question to be read.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, that might be it. Which is why I'm asking about it here. I know that $\langle\frac{1}{r}\rangle\ne -\frac{R_\infty\, h\,c}{2}$, Since the left hand side is an expectation value (nothing to do with potential energy).